# Tabular in tabular: Strange behavior of rowcolor

Tags: tables, minipage

Starting with the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 


\begin{document}     

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
    \rowcolor{yellow}  \hline
  Head 1 & Head 2 \\ 
    \hline
     15/2015 &  1 \\ 
     16/2015 &  2 \\ 
     17/2015 &  3 \\ 
     18/2015 &  4 \\ 
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{cap A} 


\end{document}
```

I get a table with yellow header:

[image]

Now I want to place a similar table to the right side. So I put both tabulars into an minipage and another tabular around:

```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} 


  \begin{document}     

  \begin{tabular}{c|c}

  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
      \rowcolor{yellow}  \hline
    Head 1 & Head 2 \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  1 \\ 
       16/2015 &  2 \\ 
       17/2015 &  3 \\ 
       18/2015 &  4 \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{cap A} 
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
      \rowcolor{yellow}  \hline
      Head A & Head B \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  A \\ 
       18/2015 &  B \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{cap B} 
  \end{minipage}

  \end{tabular}


  \end{document}
```

Both tabulars are side-by-side.

But now the whole tabulars are yellow. How do I change this and why does this happen?

[image]

When omitting minipage and using tabularx I get the same result:

```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
  \usepackage{tabularx}

  \begin{document}     

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}X@{}}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|r|r|}
      \rowcolor{yellow}  \hline
    Head 1 & Head 2 \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  1 \\ 
       16/2015 &  2 \\ 
       17/2015 &  3 \\ 
       18/2015 &  4 \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
  &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|r|r|}
      \rowcolor{yellow}  \hline
      Head A & Head B \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  A \\ 
       18/2015 &  B \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabularx}


  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The outer tabular is not doing anything useful here, but perhaps that is just an artefact of the small example.

Table cells form groups so to work across a row `\rowcolor` makes global assignments which means nested use doesn't always work as you expect, simplest is to do the nested tables in a safe box and then just copy them in.

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} 


  \begin{document}     

\sbox{0}{\begin{tabular}{|r|r|} \hline
      \rowcolor{yellow} 
    Head 1 & Head 2 \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  1 \\ 
       16/2015 &  2 \\ 
       17/2015 &  3 \\ 
       18/2015 &  4 \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}}

\sbox{2}{\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}\hline
      \rowcolor{yellow}  
      Head A & Head B \\ 
      \hline
       15/2015 &  A \\ 
       18/2015 &  B \\ 
       \hline
    \end{tabular}}

  \begin{tabular}{c|c}

  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \usebox{0}
    \captionof{table}{cap A} 
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \usebox{2}
    \captionof{table}{cap B} 
  \end{minipage}

  \end{tabular}


  \end{document}
```

Comment: I've got one more question: How do I align the minipages vertically? `\begin{minipage}[t]` doesn't work. What does work is `\begin{tabular}[t]`. But unfortunately are these the result of a xtable-call in R. So I can't set this `[t]`.

Comment: I'm using adjustbox instead of minipage. This seems to work.